# HttpWebRequest ClientCertificates remains empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl-certificate

I try to send a X509 Certificate (SSL certificate of a website) like this :

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
X509Certificate clientCert = new X509Certificate("certificate.pfx");
req.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);
```

When debugging the webservice receiving the request (everything is on the same machine as I'm just testing), `Request.ClientCertificates` remains empty.

I'm struggling with this problem. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: show your serverside and configuration

Comment: @DanielA.White Well, there's absolutely nothing on server side. It's a whole new application with the default web.config.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attaching client certificate without private key. As the result, web client cannot initiate client authentication (it requires private key) and not sending it to server. This is why you see empty client certificate there.

Comment: Might be that ! I'm checking.

Comment: Well, when looking in my X509ClientCerificate2, it says that it contains private key...
Help !

Comment: When you view it from store? Maybe, but you are importing certificate from file and that file doesn't contain private key.

Comment: No, it's when loading it from the file using X509ClientCertificate2. It does contain a private key.